# Toastr for Form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toastr

Im trying to replace javascript alerts with Toastr.  I have successfully linked both css and script.
For example: If the textbox is empty, a Toastr will pop up showing "Please enter your ID". Im new to this Thanks!

HTML Form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" role="form" onsubmit= "required()" autocomplete="off" name="loginform">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Number" name="emp_id" id="emp_id">

<button type="submit" name="login">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

Script

```
<script>
function required()
{
var empt = document.loginform.emp_id.value;
if (empt === "")
{
**// enter toastr command here**
return false;
}
else 
{
// success
return true; 
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using toastr.js so here's the documentation on how to use it

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Example:

```
toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')
```

Comment: Yes I am using Toastr.js, it works well on buttons. but not on form validations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Toastrjs](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function required(){
  var empt = document.loginform.emp_id.value;
  if (empt.length <= 0){
    toastr.error('Please enter your ID')
    return false;
  }
  else {
  // success
  return true; 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I am using Toastr.js, it works well on buttons. but not on form validations.